# Count number of occupied cells within a certain month

Tags: excel

I am trying to determine the number of occupied cells within a certain month. Say I have column 'A' filled with random dates from January to December and column 'B' has some data in it. Some of the cells is column 'B' are filled with data, others are empty. How do I restrict my search to just the cells within the specified month. I know I need to be using `COUNTA` to find the number of occupied cells, but I don't know how to force it to search only cells in column 'B' which are within the specified month in column 'A'.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Note: I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use COUNTIFS.

Example for Month February 2014:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=2014-02-01",A:A,"<2014-03-01",B:B,"<>")
```

Greetings

Axel